# Does the following robots.txt block all pages

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, search-engine-indexing

I want to knew if the following robots.txt file block the whole pages from being indexed or not.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily test in your [Google Webmaster Tools account](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en). But the answer is, no. It does not block your whole site. You block the `/cgi-bin/` directory in line three. Line two essentially explicitly allows your entire site to be crawled. See the [robots.txt documentation](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) for more on this.

Comment: Just to add, line two (`Disallow: `) is not required (the default action is to _allow_).